# Alterar estrutura de propriedade no momento da serialização JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma situação onde meu formulário HTML representa uma estrutura de dados diferente da estrutura existente no servidor.

Para exemplificar meu problema, irei apresentar uma situação hipotética, para apresentar qual solução necessito:

**Minha classe:**

```
public class Pessoa{
    public long Codigo {get;set;}
    public Estado Estado {get;set;}
}

[ModelBinder(typeof(EstadoBinder))] 
public class Estado{
    public static Estado ObtenhaEstado(long codigo){
       // Obtêm instância de estado a partir do código
    }

    public long Codigo {get;set;}
}
```

**Meu HTML:**

```
<div id='formularioPessoa'>
   <input type='text' name='Codigo' />
   <input type='text' name='Estado' />
</div>
```

Como é possível observar no trecho HTML, preciso que o input 'Estado' reflita ao objeto Estado de minha classe Pessoa.

Para a interação de CLIENT para SERVER, já consegui uma solução implementando um binder customizado, implementando a interface IModelBinder. A solução foi excelente, pois não exigiu que nenhuma classe a não ser o próprio estado conheça esta particularidade.

**Minha necessidade:**

Agora, preciso de algo para tratar a interação de SERVER para CLIENT, quando existe uma serialização de um objeto C# para um objeto JSON.

O que preciso é que, ao serializar qualquer objeto que contenha uma propriedade do tipo Estado, este serializador saiba que devo enviar um JSON nesta estrutura (abaixo, o exemplo da serialiazação de Pessoa):

```
{
  "Codigo": "1",
  "Estado": "2"
}
```

Ao invés de:

```
{
  "Codigo": "1",
  "Estado": {
              Codigo: "2"
            }
}
```

Já pesquisei muito material em inglês, inclusive buscando algo associado ao DateTime, em relação a 'Custom serializers', 'Override Json method of controller', porém, não encontrei nenhuma solução elegante como a solução que encontrei para a interação Client > Server (IModelBinder).

Uma ressalva:

- Não posso utilizar Html Helpers, nem outro código ASP.NET MVC no meu arquivo CSHTML.

Comment: Está usando JSON.NET?

Comment: Não Cigano, uso ASP.NET MVC 4 com todos os módulos default.

Comment: Há a possibilidade de amarrar um *Binder* no objeto de serialização, mas isto só vale pro JSON.NET: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Binder.htm. Se for possível usar, coloco como resposta.

Comment: Obrigado Cigano, posso incluir o JSON.NET ao meu projeto sim! Porém precisarei de todo o caminho se possível, pois não conheço a biblioteca. Desde a inclusão no Nuget até o ponto de utilizá-la na propriedade.

Answer (score 1):

Teoricamente poderia fazer assim no seu **controller**

```
    public JsonResult Pessoas()
    {

        var pessoas = db.Pessoas.Select(s => new { Codigo = s.Codigo , Estado =  s.Estado.Codigo });

        return Json(pessoas , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Precisava de algo generalizado joaoeduardorf, não irei utilizar isso apenas nesta situação. Já resolvi utilizando um JsonSerializer customizado.